# will `ls -lt` follow the accurate mtimes or just the approximate mtimes up to second?

Tags: ls, timestamps

`ls -l` only shows the modification timestamps of the files up to second. If two files have the same timestamp up to second, but were modified not exactly at the same time, will `ls -lt` order the files in the order of the accurate mtimes or just the approximate mtimes up to second (and therefore the order between the files can be arbitrary)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That very much depends on the `ls` implementation. Of those 4 found on a GNU/Linux system here:

```
$ touch a; touch c; touch b; stat -c %y a c b
2018-01-10 12:52:21.367640342 +0000
2018-01-10 12:52:21.371640148 +0000
2018-01-10 12:52:21.375639952 +0000
```

- [GNU `ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html), the one from the GNU project (from the GNU *coreutils* collection). That's the one typically found on GNU systems like Debian (Linux or kFreeBSD kernels), Cygwin or Fedora.

  ```
  $ gnu-ls -rt
  a  c  b
  ```
- The `ls` from the [Heirloom Toolchest](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html), a port of OpenSolaris tools:

  ```
  $ heirloom-ls -rt
  a  b  c
  ```
- The `ls` from [the AT&T Open Source collection](https://github.com/att/ast), possibly built in `ksh93`. Another one with quite a few fancy extensions:

  ```
  $ ast-ls -rt
  a  c  b
  $ PATH=/opt/ast/bin:$PATH ksh93 -c 'type ls; ls -rt'
  ls is a shell builtin version of /opt/ast/bin/ls
  a  c  b
  ```
- busybox (as found (or a derivative) on most (generally embedded) Linux-based systems):

  ```
  $ busybox ls -rt
  c  b  a
  ```

So, of those, GNU and ast `ls` considers the fractional second part. The others fall back to lexical comparison for files last modified within the same second. Only busybox `ls` honours the `-r` there.

In my tests, FreeBSD's `ls` also supports sub-second precision (provided they're enabled at the VFS level, see `vfs.timestamp_precision` sysctl).

`zsh`'s globs (with the `om` glob qualifier to order on modification time, `Om` for reverse order) also take the full time:

```
$ echo *(Om)
a c b
```

[`[ file1 -nt file2 ]`, where supported also generally support sub-second granularity](/a/372858).

Comment: Are the non-GNU tools violating POSIX, or does it specify rounding for the sort?

Comment: What is ast-ls?

Comment: @Random832, see edit.

Comment: @Kevin, from my reading of the spec, they are _not_ compliant in that regard. AFAICT, there's nothing in the spec that allows the subsecond part to be ignored and POSIX provides with a clear API to retrieve precise timestamps.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I don't suppose this changes the result, but did you check that you three distinct timestamps when creating the files like that? On x86 Linux, I seem to get two files with one timestamp and the third with another, or even all three with the same timestamp.

Comment: @ikkachu, you're right. I hadn't noticed that. see edit. That does change the result for ast.

Answer (score 4):

With regards to GNU's `ls` implementation, running `ls -l` will order files in alphabetical order, and `ls -lt` will order files in order of modification time, newest first, to the greatest accuracy supported by the underlying filesystem. You can check this using the `--full-time` option.

So, to answer your question, yes, to the greatest extend it can, but only when you use `-t` (otherwise, it will default to alphabetic), and are using an implementation that supports it (see 
[Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415458/142558) for more details). For example, `ext4` can support nanosecond precision, given large enough inodes to store the required timestamp data.

Comment: You should add to your answer that it only talks about GNU ls. There are many other implementations that might behave differently.

Comment: @RolandIllig added

Answer (score 1):

you can check that if you compare the output of

```
ls -lat
```

and

```
ls -lat --full-time
```

there is nothing arbitrary there about sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.

To test, create two files with a small time difference:

```
$ touch aa; sleep 0.2; touch bb
```

Check modification times:

```
$ stat -c %y bb aa
2018-01-07 20:51:19.364248042 0000
2018-01-07 20:51:19.072248226 0000
```

The list will use such difference:

```
$ ls -lt aa bb
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jan  7 20:51 bb
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Jan  7 20:51 aa
```

With `--full-time` the difference will be clear.

```
$ ls -lt --full-time aa bb
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2018-01-07 20:51:19.364248042 0000 bb
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2018-01-07 20:51:19.072248226 0000 aa
```

Comment: In the last block, I believe you have `bb` and `aa` backwards.